# SAAS application with microservices and database per tenant

Tags: database, microservices, saas

I am designing web application for multi-tenant SAAS model, where due to some regulation we decided to have one database per tenant and we are considering microservices for our middleware. But I confused bit, where microservice architecture talks about 'every microservice has their own database'. So here are my questions

1. If I use shared database for microservices, it violate concept/purpose of microservices design where they all should be isolated and any change should limited to that microservice.

I can think of a layer which mimic my database tables as DTO and every microservice communicate to database with this layer, correct me if I am wrong here.

2. If I use every microservice has their own database then its almost impossible to have one database per tenant, otherwise each microservice end-up with n number of database.

So what should be right approach to design our middleware with one database per tenant
Or if any one has better approach feel free to share.

Below is high-level design we are started with
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFaTn.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should distinguish 2 things here:

1. **Database sharding**
   Sharding is a database architecture pattern related to horizontal partitioning in which you split your database based on some logical key. In your case your logical key is your Tenant(tenantId or tenantCode). Sharding will allow you to split your data from one database to multiple physical databases. Ideally you can have a database per logical shard key. In your case this means that you can have in best case database per tenant. Keep in mind that you don't have to split it that far. If your data is not that big enough to be worth putting every tenant data to separate database start with 2 databases and put half of your tenants to 1 physical database and half to a second physical database. You can then coordinate this on your application layer by saving in some configuration or another table in database which tenant is in which database. As your data grows you can migrate and/or create additional physical databases or physical shards.
2. **Database per micro-service**
   It is one of the basic rules in micro-services architecture that each micro-service has its own database. There are multiple reasons for it some of them are:

   - Scaling
   - Isolation
   - Using different database technologies for different micro-services(if needed)
   - development team separation

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57445842/1775693). Sure it has some drawbacks but keep in mind that is one of the key rules in micro-services architecture.

**Your questions**

> If I use shared database for microservices, it violate concept/purpose
>   of microservices design where they all should be isolated and any
>   change should limited to that microservice.

If you can try to avoid shared database for multiple micro-services. If you end up doing it you should maybe consider your architectural design. Sometimes forcing one database is a indicator that some micro-services should be merged to one as the coupling between them is to big so the overhead of working with them becomes very complex.

> If I use every microservice has their own database then its almost
>   impossible to have one database per tenant, otherwise each
>   microservice end-up with n number of database.

I don't really agree that its impossible. Yes it is hard to manage but if you decided to use micro-services and you need database sharding you need to deal with the extra complexity. Sure having one database per micro-service and then for each micro-service n databases could be very challenging. 
As a solution I would suggest the following:

- Include the tenant(tenantId or tenantCode) as a column in every table in your database. This way you will be able to migrate easily later if you decide that you need to shard that table,set of tables in schema, or whole db belonging to some micro-service. As already said in the above part regarding Database sharding you can start with one Physical shard(one physical database) but already define your logical shard(in this case using the tenant info in each table).
- Separate physically the data to different shards only in the micro-services where you need it. Lets say you have 2 micro-services: product-inventory-micro-service and customers-micro-service. Lets say you have 300 million products in your product-inventory-micro-service db and only 500 000 Customers. You don't need to have a database per tenant in the customers-micro-service but in product-inventory-micro-service with 300 million records that would be very helpful performance wise.
  As I said above start small with 1 or 2 physical databases and increase and migrate during the time as the time goes your data increases and you have the need for it. This way you will save yourself some overhead in development and maintenance of your servers at least for the time that you don't need it.

Comment: I loved database sharding approach where I can start with 2 physical database and store tenant-database mapping in tenant context service/configuration table. But if Its must to have separate database per tenant (Due to some regulation with business). Can we go with approach where database per tenant having seperate schema for each microservice and no direct access of schema by other microservice.

Comment: Technically you can but the question is why are you using micro-services? Or maybe you can merge a couple of them. If you read the link I provided above you can see some argument against using 1 database for multiple micro-services. Generally this depends on your Domain. If you want to save some licences costs and avoid dealing with multiple servers you can create multiple Databases on a single SQL Server instance. This way you would still have separate databases but on the same SQL Server.

Comment: You said that you are "considering microservices for our middleware". What do you mean by that. Only using micro-services for your middleware or for your whole solution? What exactly is your middleware? Can you give some more info about that?

Comment: I have added design diagram we are starting with. Here we are considering API gateway and microservices as middleware. Where microservices communicate with each other via message bus or possibly via API gateway, aggregate result from each microservice.

Comment: I saw the diagram. That is a very uncommon design but you and your team know the best what fits your business requirement. Why did you chose to use micro-services for your middleware?

Comment: Can you please point out what is uncommon design other than database per tenant coupled with microservices. I Know database couplings is purely against microservices architecture and this is where we will consider suggestion provided here to better our design.

Comment: Why we choose microservices, is due to we decouple our bussiness modules and quick deployment for business changes, we are still in very beginning phase of our design, exploring couple of variants. So every suggestion counts to improve our design. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Our application is SaaS and multi-tenant with a microservices architecture.  We do indeed use 1 database per service, though in some cases it's actually just a separate schema per tenant, not a separate instance.

The key concept in "database per service" is all to do with avoiding sharing of tables/documents between services and less to do with exactly how you implement that.  If two services are both accessing the same table, that becomes a point of tight coupling between the services as well as a common point of failure - two things microservices are designed to avoid.

> Database-per-service means don't share persistence between multiple services, how you implement that is up to you.

Multi-tenancy is another challenge and there are multiple ways to approach it.  In our case (where regulations do not dictate our architecture) we have designed our Tenant-aware table-structures with `TenantId` as part of the Primary Key.  Each Tenant-aware service implements this separation and our Authorization service helps keep users within the boundaries of their assigned Tenant(s).

If you are required to have more separation than key/value separation, I would look to leverage schemas as a great tool to segregate both data and security:

- You could have a database instance (say a SQL Server instance) per microservice, and within each instance have a schema per tenant.
- That may be overkill at the start, and I think you'd be safe to do a schema per service/tenant combination until that number grew to be a problem.

In either case, you'd probably want to write some tooling in your DB of choice to help manage your growing collection of schemas, but unless you are going to end up with thousands of tenants, that should get you pretty far down the road.

The last point to make is that you're going to lean heavily on an Integration bus of some sort to keep your multiple, independent data stores in sync.  I strongly encourage you to spend as much time on designing that as you do the rest of your persistence as those events become the lifeblood of the system.  For example, in our multi-tenant setup, creating a new tenant touches 80% of our other services (by broadcasting a message) so that those services are ready to interact with the new tenant.  There are some integration events that need to happen quickly, others that can take their time, but managing all those moving parts is a challenge.

Comment: SQL Server instance per microservice and within each instance have a schema per tenant could be one solution, where i can separate data per tenant. But in this case when a new tenant added, I have to update all services to add new schema.

Comment: Yes, true.  It's not hard, though, to add tooling to do that.  You could have a stored procedure that takes in a few parameters and builds out your new schema complete with user, tables, etc.